# How to async code Blazor Dependency Injection in components?

Tags: async-await, dependency-injection, blazor, maui-blazor

I'm starting to study MAUI Blazor to migrate some apps I have in Android an iOS. I'm struggling a bit with Dependency Injection with Blazor components.

Here is the Card I've created to list some items:

```
<h3>LoteCard</h3>

<div class="row">
    @foreach (Lote l in lstLotesFiltrada)
    {
        <div class="col-sm-4 p-2">
            <div class="lote-card">
                <div class="lote-card-header">
                    <h3>l.numLote:l.pesoLote</h3>
                </div>
                if (visible){
                    <p> this is visible</p>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>


@code {
    [Parameter]
    public bool visible { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public List<Lote> lstLotesFiltrada { get; set; } = new List<Lote>();

}
```

And here is the code for the CardComponent:

```
<LoteCard lstLotesFiltrada="lstLotesFiltrada" visible="isVisible"/>


@code {
    private bool isVisible = true;

    private List<Lote> lstLotesFiltrada = new List<Lote>();

    [Inject]
    private ILotesManager lotesManager { get; set; } = new LotesManager();

    protected override async void OnInitialized()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();

        loadLotes();

        int x = 1;

    }

    private async void loadLotes()
    {
        List<Lote> tmpLstLotesFiltrada = await lotesManager.getLoteByIdPropriedade(idPropriedade: "-Mfp3q1ma0ZkFsIUXqyE");

        lstLotesFiltrada = tmpLstLotesFiltrada;

    }
```

The problem is that when I call "loadLotes()" it awaits the result. But, the code moves on and the forLoop is executed at the Card with an empty list. Right after that the "getLote..." method returns the list with items.

The order of execution is:

1. Fire loadLotes;
2. "x=1"
3. ForLoop at the Card
4. "lstLotesFiltrada = tmpLstLotesFiltrada"

I understand this is related to the async code but am struggligng to see the solution.

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: There's no asynchronous code here. Just putting `async` in a method's signature doesn't make it asynchronous. The Blazor tutorials show that components have specialized asynchronous methods like `override async Task OnInitializedAsync()`, `override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()` etc. Those callbacks are called asynchronously by Blazor itself. Blazor never uses `async void`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your async method should return a Task, and you should override the async `OnInitializedAsync` correctly.

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
  await base.OnInitializedAsync();

  await loadLotes();

  int x = 1;
}

private async Task loadLotes()
{
  List<Lote> tmpLstLotesFiltrada = await 
    lotesManager.getLoteByIdPropriedade(idPropriedade: "-Mfp3q1ma0ZkFsIUXqyE");

  lstLotesFiltrada = tmpLstLotesFiltrada;
}
```

As per the docs:

> For methods other than event handlers that don't return a value, you
> should return a Task instead, because an async method that returns
> `void` can't be awaited. Any caller of such a method must continue to
> completion without waiting for the called async method to finish.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/async-return-types#void-return-type

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing, but the development environment hasn't been your friend here.  It's probably added the async modifiers when you typed await.

There is only one place to use:

```cs
    override async void EventHandler()
```

And that's in an event handler.

Quote from one of the authors of *async await* - https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/how-async-await-really-works/

> async void is arguably one of the most divisive features added as part of async/await. It was added for one reason and one reason only: event handlers.

**ALWAYS** use:

```cs
    private async Task loadLotes()
    {
       // an await
    }
```

Or

```cs
    private Task loadLotes()
    {
       // some sync operations
      return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

Doing the second ensures the dev environment doesn't sneak an *async void* in under the radar.  `Task.CompletedTask` is a compiler cached object so carries very little overhead.

You've also turned `OnInitialized` into an *async void*.

```cs
protected override async void OnInitialized()
```

If you need to do async work in initialization you should use the async version

```cs
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
```